# File function in makefile takes args prefixed by '@' symbol

Tags: make

This code excerpt is from Chapter 8.6 of GNU makefile manual.

What does @$@.in for file function arg in a makefile mean? and why are shell commands like rm prefixed by '@' symbol

```
program: $(OBJECTS)
     $(file >$@.in,$^)
     $(CMD) $(CMDFLAGS) @$@.in
     @rm $@.in
```

File function syntax is

```
$(file op filename[,text])
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are three unrelated uses of `@` here.

In `$@`, the character `@` is the name of an [automatic variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_0024_0040) that can be used in a rule. The value of that variable is the target that the rule is building.

When `@` is used at the very beginning of a recipe (command) line, just after the tab character, it causes the command [not to be printed](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_0040-_0028in-recipes_0029) when it's about to be executed.

The character `@` elsewhere isn't special.

Thus, in your example, to build `program`:

1. The [`file` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-file) is invoked. It writes the dependencies of the target (`$^` automatic variable) to the file `program.in`.
2. Whatever command is stored in the variable `CMD` is executed, with the parameters stored in the variable `CMDFLAGS`, plus the extra parameter `@program.in`. What this does depends on what `CMD` is.
3. The command `rm program.in` is executed, without printing it first.

A few commands treat a parameter starting with `@` as indicating a file from which to read more parameters. This is a DOS convention which came about because DOS had a stringent limit on the command line length and no way to interpolate the output of a command into a command line. It is uncommon in the Unix world since Unix doesn't have these limitations. The effect of the recipe is thus likely the same as

```
$(CMD) $(CMDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS)
```

Answer (score 3):

[@ prefix](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_0040-_0028in-recipes_0029) in line suppress *echoing* of the line.

By default, `make` prints each line of `Makefile` before it is executed. When lines starts with `@`, those lines won't be printed.

Without `@`:

```
$ cat > Makefile
hello:                                                                          
    echo hello world
$ make hello
echo hello world
hello world
```

With `@`:

```
$ cat > Makefile
hello:                                                                          
    @echo hello world
$ make hello
hello world
```

A note that only `@` at starting of line cause suppressing *echoing*. `>$@.in` or `@$@.in` are just normal strings, and `$@` in it will be expanded:

```
$ cat hello
hello:
    @echo @$@.in
$make hello
@hello.in
```

Comment: this answer doesn't say, why `>$@.in` is used as a file mode... but it is useful in its own way.. thanks cuonglm...